# Java script logic error

Tags: javascript

I am new to Java scripting and need quick help. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> GeoLocation Application </title>
<script>
$counter=0;
while ($counter < 10) {
if (!navigator.geolocation) {
  alert('Your browser does not support geolocation');
  } else {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
  document.write("Count ",$counter,"<br>");
  }

  $counter ++;
 }

 function success(position) {
   lat = position.coords.latitude;
   lng = position.coords.longitude;
  alert (lat +','+lng);
  document.write("calling update mysql");
  //document.location='update_java_data.php?lat=' + lat+'&lng='+lng;
  }

  function error(error) {
     alert('an erro occured, error code is '+error);
     }
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1> Hello </h1>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get coordinates using navigator 10 times. But when I am seeing only a quick list of counter display from 0 to 9, but only once it displays ""calling update mysql". 
To me it means it only executed success function once.

Any idea how I can make it get the coordinate 10 times (means it should also call success function 10 times I guess)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest instead looking at using the setInterval function to do your lat/long collection at specified intervals...  If what you have above runs successfully, it would probably collect the same point 10 times quickly.

So, since you do those function calls without any type of a wait/interval, they all fire off at basically the same time (0-9 counter display)...  As for only seeing the 'calling update mysql' once, I would imagine that it has something to do with you changing the location of the window to a different url, and the other calls not being able to reach the success function since you have already mo

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I have put the full code (with HTMK and body tags etc so that you have full picture). I have commented out the line which was transferring control to the php page but still it is display 'calling update mysql' only once and firefox browser is goes in a loop (with rotating circle).

Comment: OK, so a couple of things are going on here.  Like I said, you are using a while loop, so all of those requests fire off in virtually no time at all. However the geolocation api may take some time to complete your request since it has to prompt the user for permission anyways.  Since browsers don't remember their permission for geolocation from call to call, you need to use a different function (watchPosition) on the navigator.geolocation object.  Check out this site:[link](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html).  Also, for a loop that has a counter, in the future, just use a for loop!